# Error on save of articles and categories

Tags: extensions, category, joomla3.8

I'm getting this error when I try to save new category. However, the category is created after I refresh listing. Any ideas?

```
Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::getParams()
```

Joomla version 3.8.1
PhP 7.0
All extensions are up-to-date and I disabled any that are not specifically joomla 3.8 compliant
Also running civicrm 4.7.25

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very common now - and it is usually caused by a manual update of the Joomla website, which typically results in a `libraries` folder that is not compatible with the current Joomla website. A quick resolution to this problem is to rename your libraries folder and then recopy a libraries folder from a Joomla 3.8.1 install. See [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/call-to-undefined-method-japplicationsiteisclient-when-updating-to-joomla-3-8).

If that doesn't help, then try recoyping the `administrator/components/com_content` folder to your Joomla website (from Joomla 3.8.1) after renaming the old `com_content` folder.

Answer (score 0):

*Take these simple steps ...*

**Global Check-in...** 
/administrator/index.php?option=com_checkin

**Clean cache...** 
/administrator/index.php?option=com_cache

**Clean expired cache...** 
/administrator/index.php?option=com_cache&view=purge

*and then...*

**Fix database...** 
/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=database

***Finally, try again.***